# Returning an arraylist in onResponse()

Tags: android, retrofit2

I use retrofit2 to get api.

In onResponse function, I want to return a arraylist to use in main activity. But I cannot return arraylist.

This is my function:

```
public void getData(){

    ArrayList<ModelHomePHHS> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    apiIterface = ApiClient.getClient().create(APIIterface.class);
    Call<ListItem> call = apiIterface.getAll("Basic FjBsAEVv6w5zzNbqbp7pDqNg6sQC/LdXVajRoxf8hhg=");
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ListItem>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ListItem> call, Response<ListItem> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                final ListItem item = response.body();
                //    ArrayList<ModelHomePHHS> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
                Log.e("server", "==load api ==");
                ArrayList<ModelHomePHHS> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
                if (item != null) {
                    Log.e("server", "count --> " + item.getCount());
                    for (int i= 0; i< item.getCount(); i++){
                        Log.e("server", "==load id == " + item.getListTeachers().get(i).getId());
                        Log.e("server", "==load name == " +  item.getListTeachers().get(i).getFullName());
                        Log.e("server", "==load avatar == " + item.getListTeachers().get(i).getAvatar());
                        Log.e("server", "==load saved == "+ item.getListTeachers().get(i).getSaved());
                        Log.e("server", "==load api ==");
                        arrayList.add(new ModelHomePHHS(
                                item.getListTeachers().get(i).getId(),
                                item.getListTeachers().get(i).getFullName(),
                                item.getListTeachers().get(i).getAvatar(),
                                item.getListTeachers().get(i).getSaved()
                                // item.getListTeachers().get(i).getSubjects()
                        ));
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ListItem> call, Throwable t) {
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `List` in your code ,you should change the `call<>` .And use
like this `Call<List<ListItem>> getList();` in your code .

1.change the call

```
@GET("your_url")
Call<List<ListItem>> getList();
```

2.then you try to set in your response

```
public void onResponse(Call<List<ListItem>> call, Response<List<ListItem>> response) {
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have to replace this:

```
public void onResponse(Call<ListItem> call, Response<ListItem> response)
```

to:

```
public static ArrayList<ModelHomePHHS> onResponse(Call<ListItem> call, Response<ListItem> response)
```

and at the end `return arrayList;`

Comment: thanks for your comment. but it's not work for me. Because onResponse work in other thread, i cannot use values in there.

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing:

```
public void onResponse(Call<List<ListItem>> call, Response<List<ListItem>> response)
```